# Image is not showing in PDF in yii2 PHP on different environments (Testing environment, Beta environments)

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, mpdf

Problem:

Facing one problem in displaying images in PDF in yii2 PHP on different environments.
The image showing on PDF in the Local environment, Testing environment but it is not showing on the Beta environment.

Requirement:

Runtime we can have multiple dynamic records. And for each record, there is a date, code, value, and image. And in  result, we have to create a PDF for these records. If 1 record in runtime then PDF shows 1 record, if 10 then PDF should have 10 rows for each individual record, respectively.

In Yii2 PHP we are using https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf this extension for generating PDFs.

Solution 1 which we tried:

1. Prepare the records in Loop in HTML format. Pass image URL directly in img src tag. and prepare PDF.

```
  $table = '
                        
        <center>Records</center>
        <br><br>
        <center>
        <table border = "1">

        <tr>

        <th style="width: 175px;">Date</th>
        <th style="width: 100px;">Code</th>
        <th style="width: 50px;">Value</th>
        <th style="width: 50px;">Image</th>
        </tr>
        ';

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $date = $model->date;
            $code = $model->code;
            $value = $model->value;
            $img_url = "https://test.com/".$model->image;
           
            $table .= "
            <tr>
            <td>$date</td>
            <td>$code</td>
            <td>$value</td>";
            
            if (!empty($img_url)) {
                $table.='
                <td><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="code" width="100"></td>

                ';
            }
        }

        $table .= '
        </tr>
        </table>
        </center>
        ';
```

We are preparing data in loop.

Now below we are rendering pdf.

```
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            'content' =>$table,
            'filename' => "records.pdf",
        ]);
         $pdf->render();
```

Solution 2: Follow the solution 1, but instead of passing image URL, encode image into base 64 and display the base 64 encoded data in img src.

```
  $table = '
                        
        <center>Records</center>
        <br><br>
        <center>
        <table border = "1">

        <tr>

        <th style="width: 175px;">Date</th>
        <th style="width: 100px;">Code</th>
        <th style="width: 50px;">Value</th>
        <th style="width: 50px;">Image</th>
        </tr>
        ';

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $date = $model->date;
            $code = $model->code;
            $value = $model->value;
            $img_url = "https://test.com/".$model->image;
            $image = file_get_contents($img_url);
            $imagedata = base64_encode($image);
           
            $table .= "
            <tr>
            <td>$date</td>
            <td>$code</td>
            <td>$value</td>";
            
            if (!empty($img_url)) {
                $table.='
                <td><img src="'."data:image/png;base64, ".$imagedata.'" alt=" code" width="100"></td>

                ';
            }
        }

        $table .= '
        </tr>
        </table>
        </center>
        ';
```

Now render.

```
 $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            'content' =>$table,
            'filename' => "records.pdf",
        ]);
         $pdf->render();
```

We have tried both this solutions.
Local Environment => Working
Testing Server Environment => Working

Beta Server Environment => **Not Working**

Can anyone tell why it giving error on different environments? Even though all the settings/package/version are correct

Comment: *"why it giving error"* Are we supposed to guess the error message?

Comment: _"Not Working"_ is not a good problem description. And if you notice differences between environments, you need to learn about configuration changes. E.g. you could compare outputs of phpinfo() across those systems to learn about differences, see https://php.net/phpinfo .